# I want to fetch data from datetime column in this form '2015-jan-1'

Tags: php, codeigniter

> This is my model

```
function get_archive_links(){
        //$this->db->select('date');
        $this->db->select("date, date_format(date, 'f jS, Y')");
       // $this->db->group_by('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)');
        $query = $this->db->get('blog');
        $results['chart_data'] = $query->result();
        return $results;

    }
```

> This is my controller

```
public function linechart(){
    $result = $this->linechart->get_archive_links();
    $data['chart_data'] = $result['chart_data'];
    $this->load->view('linechart', $data);
}
```

> I am getting this

```
2016-01-01 02:20:36.000000
```

> I need this
>   2016-jan-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are getting date in this variable, `$chart_data['date']` than use this:

```
<?
    $date = date("Y-M-d", strtotime($chart_data['date']));
?>
```

Comment: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given

Comment: print_r($chart_data); and check the indexes and use the correct one.. @Osama

Answer (score 0):

use date function to formate date according to your requirement.

```
public function linechart(){
    $result = $this->linechart->get_archive_links();
    $data['chart_data'] = date('Y-M-d', strtotime($result['chart_data']));
    $this->load->view('linechart', $data);
}
```

for more information check this:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Comment: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given

Comment: Please use this..........$data['chart_data'] = date('Y-M-d', strtotime($result['chart_data']));

Comment: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: print_r($result['char_data']) and check the correct index and use that index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in select statement itself like this:-
`select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%b-%d') from test` 
Refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d2e0/4 & this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp